# Converting queue into non decreasing order in minimum moves with only operation being insertion at the end

Tags: data-structures, queue, logic

X wants to arrange a queue of students in non decreasing order of their heights. They are currently standing at random. If the only allowed operation is to pick a student and send that student to the end of the queue, in how many minimum moves can X achieve the goal?

```
Example: 
input:
3 
3 2 1 
output: 
2
```

pushing 2 to the end and then 3.
I don't know how to find out if my logic is correct, I was asked to code this in a contest and I wasn't given any tutorial at the end of it. Can someone tell me if the logic is correct? I have added comments to explain the code.I couldn't find same question on codeforces or hackerrank, I don't know how else I can search such a question. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n,i,j,k,cnt;
    cin>>n;

    //n is the number of elements in the array

    int a[n+n],b[n+n];

    //reading the elements, and storing them in 2 arrays a and b
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
        b[i]=a[i];
    }
    sort(a,a+n);

    //array a has elements in sorted order
    //array b has elements of the given order as per question
    //cnt holds the answer required


//We pick each height from sorted array, check its number of inversions in 
//original array. Add this to count, add the heights to end of original 
//array, set these numbers to -1 in their actual position and assume that in 
//original array after 'n', elements are sorted. This will ensure optimal answer, I think.    


    for(i=0,cnt=0,k=n;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n && a[i]!=b[j];j++)
        {
            if(b[j]>a[i] && b[j]!=-1)
            {
                cnt++;
                b[k++]=b[j];
                b[j]=-1;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<cnt;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is that `4` in your example a typo?

Comment: My bad, it is 3. Edited it.